# How to get event when iframe src is changed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-hooks

I am going to get event when iframe src is changed using useEffect/useRef in React.

I tried myself but not working well.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the iframe in your form loader? In the react application? Where is the event - in your react application within the iframe? Are you posting a browser message and listing to that browser message or an onChange on the src of an iframe in your react application?

When the src value is provided to an iframe, it is created so a new iframe is created - so there will be no new event within the application if that is the react application, just a new application.

On the assupmtion that you are creating a react application with the src, maybe what you want an onload event for the application, then to post a browser message and then listen for the browser message in your application, but note your applicaiton will need to be running before the message is sent and sadly ios and mac is slow to load so your applicaiton may not have loaded before the message is sent so you may have to post a message to the form loader from the app to tell the form loader it is ready to get messages then send the message to the app with the browser messages that you want to send....

An issue i have been through recently. Hope you find some value in some of this.

Comment: At first time, iframe src is null, but when user click button, iframe loads a website.

Comment: Just have one on click of the button? Where is the message going to be going to / from? Think of an iframe as a paper wall / new app - you can't communicate between them other than say posting / listening for browser messages.